# itunes9 and the missing "display album artwork"

Tags: ipod, itunes, album-art

Before iTunes 9, there was a "Display album artwork" checkbox. By disabling then reenabling it you could rebuild the album artwork database on the iPod (when it gets corrupt by programs like Songbird).

However, I cannot seem to find that checkbox in iTunes 9. It is gone forever, or just hidden?

**How can I rebuild the album artwork database on an iPod when it gets corrupt?**

The album artwork is embedded into the files, so I just need to rebuild the artwork database in `{iPod}\iPod_Control\Artwork` so the iPod displays them correctly. Retransferring all the media again to the iPod would be my last option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[foobar2000](http://www.foobar2000.org/) and [mediamonkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com/) are able to recreate the artwork database, based purely on the embedded album artwork.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this option has been removed in iTunes 9, with no equivalent available.

The closest thing to a workaround would be to:

- Select all your songs (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>)
- Right click > "Clear downloaded artwork"

  [image]
- Confirm by clicking "Clear downloaded artwork"
- Right click > "Get album artwork"

  [image]

However, I have not tested this as I don't have a corrupted iPod so I cannot be 100% sure if it works or not.

Comment: where should the "clear downloaded artwork" option be? in the context menu? i can't find it...

Comment: The the right click-ed contextual menu.

Comment: nope, no such entry in my menu, i ll have to check the mac version as well, but i am pretty sure to not have seen such an option.

Comment: They should be there. If they are not, I suspect it is because iTunes automatically downloaded the album art for that album. If it is not there, simply ignore that step and see if it still works.

Comment: the context menu you are talking about is only available in the normal media library, not at the songs on the ipod ...